# Installing Cordova plugin

Tags: android, cordova, plugins

When I try to install a Cordova plugin via the CLI
 for example:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
```

I am getting the following response:

```
Error: Current working directory is not a Cordova-based project.
```

I'm guessing that Android Studio has performed some kind of project conversion since I initially created the app..

Could somebody point me in the direction of either fixing this, or installing a plugin more manually please?

Comment: Android Studio should not modify the cordova folder structure, are you running the cordova command from the root of the cordova project or the android project (It should be run from the cordova root)?

Comment: Can you please retry the command with the flag --verbose to see if there is additional informations that can help find the cause of the error ?  `cordova plugin add --verbose org.apache.cordova.camera`

Comment: Here you go: http://pastebin.com/w1ZXySNF

Comment: Turns out keeping my Cordova projects inside a Dropbox folder is the reason they stop being Cordova projects... Dropbox doesn't upload the hidden directories, then syncs and effectively removes the local hiddens to match. Not a good idea to store Cordova projects in Dropbox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new dummy project, installed the plugin to that, and then copied over the files into the real project.

I've tested this with a few plugins now and it seems to work every time, so for anybody else finding this issue:

1)

```
$ mkdir TempProject
$ cd TempProject
$ cordova create .
$ cordova platform add android
$ cordova plugin add plugin-name
```

2) Copy folders from

```
/plugins/[plugin-folder]
/platforms/android/assets/www/plugins/[plugin-folder]
/platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/[plugin-folder]
```

3) Check these files for updates

```
/platforms/android/android.json
/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml
/platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js
/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that you are using this command in the root folder of your project, not in the platform or platform android.

If this still happens, it's because a .cordova directory is missing (its a hidden folder), probably you have to regenerate the project

Comment: I'm running from the root folder, that contains config.xml, hooks, out, platforms and plugins.

I created the app via "cordova create ." and "cordova platform add android". Then from within Android Studio, "Import Project" -> ... -> "Create from existing sources".

Comment: I created a new project and installed the plugin to that, then copied the folder out of plugins and into the real project. I also checked the Manifest file and found only one additional permission to add. This doesn't appear to be all that is needed though, as I still can't use the functions this plugin is supposed to have added?

Comment: If you copied the plugin to the project/plugins folder, you dont need anything else, even the manifest properties are updated once you build the platform. If you copied to the platform/android/..., you should check the manifest, src folder, and more.

Comment: I copied the project folder /plugins/cordova-plugin-camera folder from the dummy project to the real project, then amended /platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml and /platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml but the function this plugin is supposed to provide, navigator.camera.getPicture(), just results in "Cannot read property 'getPicture' of undefined". Am I missing something or should I assume the plugin and/or my code is broken?

Comment: Found additional amends to make in /platforms/android/android.json and /platforms/android/assets/www/cordova_plugins.js , and I found additional folders /platforms/android/src/org/apache/cordova/camera and /platforms/android/assets/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-camera to copy. Now it seems to be working!